# Have finished, just

Tags: past-simple

My friend learns English. And he often uses “I have just finished”. Yet in America I hear people say, “I just finished”. Which one is correct/more correct?

(I read this ['Have just finished' vs. 'Just finished': What is the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107186/have-just-finished-vs-just-finished-what-is-the-difference) but it seemed a little confusing — something about British English, simple past and present perfect. Could someone give a simpler answer?)

Comment: Khan's answer to that question seems simple enough to me. "I have finished" (the present perfect tense) is more commonly used in British English. Maybe your friend's English teacher is British?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

I hope that is simple enough. If you want more, see below about British English, simple past and present perfect.

In American English, the form "I just finished" (past tense) is very common. In British English, a present perfect is more often used "I've just finished".

Comment: Ah. Yes that seems very blunt and right to the point. Yes my friends teacher is probably British. Or maybe just a l lot of teachers maybe abroad go for just BrE. I will read a bit about more of the differences. I’ll just tell them that some things could be a bit different, but both apparently right.